# Combinations when repetitions are allowed

Tags: probability, combinations

Let there be $10$ gifts of $3$ kinds $(A,B,C)$; of which we have $5A,3B,2C$. If we are supposed to select $7$ gifts out of these, what is the probability that we pick a combination of $4A,2B,1C \ ?$

The solution to the problem is given as $\frac{{5\choose4}*{3\choose2}*{2\choose1}}{10\choose7}$

What I don't understand is, how come the number of ways of selecting $4 A$s is $5\choose4$?, wouldn't it be $1$? because all $A$s are same and hence the number of ways of picking up $4A$s should be $1$ right? Any help in understanding this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You have 5 A, choosing 4 of them is equivalent to choosing the one you actually don't choose. So if this makes more sense to you then you have 5 ways of doing so.

Comment: While yes, if you consider gifts of the same type to be indistinguishable, there is only one way of selecting four gifts of type A... this does *not* correlate with any natural interpretation of having selected the gifts randomly.  Compare this to the problem where we have $1000$ gifts of two kinds, $999$ of which are gifts of type A and only one of which is of type B.  Having picked one gift at random, what is the probability of it as having been of type A?  According to your broken logic, you might have said the answer was $\frac{1}{1000}$ or of $\frac{1}{2}$, both of which are wrong.

Comment: It is far more natural to use the interpretation where each gift is distinguishable, which would have led to the more natural answer of $\frac{\binom{999}{1}\binom{1}{0}}{\binom{1000}{1}}=\frac{999}{1000}$.  In doing so, we can use outcomes in our sample space which are actually equally likely to occur which helps calculations tremendously.  Recall, we prefer equiprobable sample spaces so we can calculate probabilities using ratios.  There are two outcomes to playing a lottery, you win or you lose, but the probability of winning isn't $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, my apologies for late reply. But in the case of permutations shouldn't we consider like things to be completely indistinguishable?

Comment: Imagine a bag containing 999 red marbles, each of which numbered uniquely and one blue piece of candy like a jawbreaker.  Now imagine two people, one of which is blind and cannot tell the pieces apart and another person who can easily tell each and every piece apart.  Are you suggesting that the blind person only has a probability of 1/2 to not draw the candy while instead the person with sight has a 999/1000 chance to not draw the candy?  The whole point is that if you want to calculate probability by counting and taking ratios, the outcomes *must* be equally likely to occur.

Comment: If you count where like objects are identical and you only counted the two possibilities, you either drew the candy or you didn't, then these outcomes are *not* equally likely.  Now... although the objects might to us be identical, we may make the simplification to the problem to make sure that the events we are working with are equally likely by pretending that there is some labeling that we can't perceive, just like how the blind person couldn't see the numbers on the marbles.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the gifts are lined up in a row, and numbered $1$ to $10$.  There are $10$ slips of paper, numbered $1$ to $10$ in a hat.  You draw $7$ slips, and get the gifts with hose numbers.  So, you get four $A$'s if you choose slips $1,2,3,4,x,y,z$ where $5<x<y<z<11$ and also if you choose slips $1,2,3,5,x,y,z$ or slips $1,2,4,5,x,y,z$  and so on.